# Delete a self signed certificate created using makecert

Tags: c#, iis-7, x509certificate

I created a self-signed certificate using the following command:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=aaa" -sky exchange -ss my -sr localmachine aaa.cer
```

This certificate shows up as a server certificate in my IIS manager, which is what i want.

Now I wish to delete this programmatically (`C#`), what is the command line by which I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete it just like you delete any other file in C#:

```
        string path = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\aaa.cer";
        FileInfo myfileinf = new FileInfo(path);
        myfileinf.Delete();
```

Comment: There is no aaa.cer in that path or C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the solution is,

```
certmgr -del -c -n "aaa" -s -r localMachine My
```

Comment: that's not deleting it programmically via C#!

Comment: Throw the above at the `Process` class and it is  ;)